# Tailwind Alpine.js hide show menu with checkbox checked

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am using Alpine.js in my new Tailwind project and now I am stuck, while it has been working great.

I made a hamburger menu icon with a checkbox and now I want the menu to actually show up.

Not really getting any closer from reading the Alpine documentation, it has a lot of info on buttons but not on checkboxes.

I want to initially not show the menu, check the checkbox ie. press the hamburger menu icon and show the mobile menu. Clicking the icon again ie. unchecking the checkbox, hides the menu again.

My code now:

```
         <label for="check-menu" class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer w-70px">
          <input type="checkbox" id="check-menu" class="hidden" x-model="show" />
          <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-full h-7px mx-0 my-7px hamburger"></span>
          <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-full h-7px mx-0 my-7px hamburger"></span>
          <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-3/4 ml-25pc h-7px my-7px hamburger"></span>
        </label>

        <div x-text="show">
          Menu on mobile
        </div>
```

The site gives console errors and is not loading anymore..

I also tried the @click event with .self, not working as well (the mobile menu doesnt show).

Anyone has any clue how to make this happen?

Comment: Have you defined the `show` variable?

Comment: According to the docs, I don't see it declared.. I have the x-model on the checkbox.. : https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#single-checkbox-with-boolean

Comment: You always need to use `x-data`. As you see at the top of the referenced page, there is a `x-data`. Later it is omitted to make the documentation more compact for the different input types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to always mark an Alpine.js component with [`x-data` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data) and define the reactive variables there.

```
<div x-data="{show: false}">
     <label for="check-menu" class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer w-70px">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check-menu" class="hidden" x-model="show" />
      <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-full h-7px mx-0 my-7px hamburger"></span>
      <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-full h-7px mx-0 my-7px hamburger"></span>
      <span class="duration-[400ms] bg-white rounded-md w-3/4 ml-25pc h-7px my-7px hamburger"></span>
    </label>

    <div x-show="show">
      Menu on mobile
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't show the Menu on mobile, it just shows the text "false" and "true"..

Comment: It needs to be this:

 <div x-show="show">
      Menu on mobile
    </div>

Comment: Yes, of course. I thought it was an intentional debug message. I corrected my answer.